# How to +/add text together to get total C#

Tags: c#

I have basically two text which I would like to plus together to get a total.

What I need this to do is :

*price.Text* = 50.50
**addprice.Text** = 140.50

*price.Text* + **addprice.Text**

to get : 191.00

I tried looking everywhere to find how to get this working, Any ideas/suggestions. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform mathematical operations on strings directly, you need to use a numeric data type for that.

Let's do this step by step:

1. Convert your texts to numbers. You can use [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0) for that. Think about what you want to happen if the text does not contain a valid number.
2. Add your numbers.
3. Convert your sum back to text. You can use [`Decimal.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=net-5.0) for that.

Implementation is left as an exercise, but the SO crowd will surely help you if you get stuck.

Note: Since your numbers seem to be monetary values, you should [use `decimal` rather than `double` or `float`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761/87698).

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = Convert.ToDecimal(price.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(addPrice.Text);
```

Convert your strings to `decimal` then sum and if you want to convert back to string just: `total.ToString()`

Comment: I'd recommend the `Decimal.TryParse` over `Convert.ToDecimal` 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

As string:

`string total = (decimal.Parse(price.Text) + decimal.Parse(addPrice.Text)).ToString();`

or as decimal:

`decimal total = decimal.Parse(price.Text) + decimal.Parse(addPrice.Text);`

Comment: What if addPrice.Text is "Have a nice day!"? Never trust user input!

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse those texts into a numbers (floats in this case).

```
float priceNumber = 0;
float addPriceNumber = 0;
if(float.TryParse(price.Text, out priceNumber) && float.TryParse(addprice.Text, out addPriceNumber )) {
    //Here, the priceNumber and addPriceNumber has numbers stored as float
    float result = priceNumber + addPriceNumber;
} else {
    //Error parsing, wrong format of numbers
}
```

Docs: [float.TryParse / Single.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Some knowledge about parsing: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: Do not use floating point types for monetary amounts. (See [@Heinzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66887473/982149))